# Where can I find the images folder after I deploy the outlook add-in?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I stored all my images in the image folder which I created inside visual studio project. However, after I deployed and installed the outlook add-in project, all the images cannot be found and loaded.

Is there any way I can preserve those image inside my current project?

The directory path of my image folder would be like this:

> C:\Users\yyang\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\MyProject\MyProject\Image

Hope you can give me some suggestions,

Comment: What did you already try?

Answer (score 0):

> However, after I deployed and installed the outlook add-in project, all the images cannot be found and loaded.

Where did you install the add-in? Did you check out the target folder?

It looks like you didn't include images to the installer. Make sure that you set the **Build Action** property in the *Properties window* to the **Content** value. Read more about that in the [How to: Specify Which Files Are Published by ClickOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kzy0fky2.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article in MSDN.